# A ListPlot with multiple lines, fill to the axis, no thickness of the lines, and all fill in the same color

Tags: plotting

I have created the ListPlot shown below (from data in a multidimensional list), but it is not exactly what I aimed for. I aimed for everything shown, except I do not want any lines to border the shading.

How do I get rid of the lines?

My current code is:

```
ListPlot[{Part[mat, 1, 1, 6], Part[mat, 1, 2, 6], Part[mat, 1, 3, 6], Part[mat, 1, 4, 6], Part[mat, 1, 5, 6]}, Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> {{blue , Thickness[0]}, {blue, Thickness[0]}, {blue, Thickness[0]}, {blue, Thickness[0]}, {blue, Thickness[0]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `PlotStyle -> Transparent, FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity@0.3, Blue]` to get the filling without lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Accumulate @ RandomReal[10, {5, 10}];
```

You can use the (undocumented) sub-option `"LineOpacity" -> 0` for `PlotStyle`:

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, "LineOpacity" -> 0]]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 Filling -> Prepend[1 -> Axis][# -> {#2} & @@@ Partition[Reverse@Range[5], 2, 1]], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive["LineOpacity" -> 0], 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, Range[5]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, a slight variation on Lukas's suggestion in the comments:

```
ListLinePlot[data,
  Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotStyle -> None, 
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, Blue]]
```

[image]

Comment: It's also possible to use the multi-argument form to `Filling` to override an `Opacity[0]` in the standard `PlotStyle`.